# AndroidAnnotations- execute method directly after a specific @ViewById and before others @ViewById

Tags: android, findviewbyid, android-annotations

I'd like to know if it's possible to execute a methode directly after a specific @ViewById and before others @ViewById.

```
@ViewById
CostumView view1;

@ViewById
ListView list;

void myMethod(){
    view1.set...
}
```

also I'd like to know how can I force the first injection to be the first.

thanks.

code without AA
the main and fan layouts must be set only by java .

```
private FanView fan;
   private ListView list;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.test);
            fan = (FanView) findViewById(R.id.fan_view);
            fan.setViews(R.layout.main, R.layout.fan);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

if the list is in the main or fan layout the findViewById of MyActivity_ returns null :)

(if I use @AfterViews) the generated code will be somthing like that :

```
                setContentView(R.layout.test);
                fan = (FanView) findViewById(R.id.fan_view);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);//returns null
                fan.setViews(R.layout.main, R.layout.fan);
```

Comment: Why do you want to invoke method after particular injection? Check if `@AfterViews` would be enough.

Comment: updated, @AfterViews isn't enought for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no annotation allowing to execute an instruction between the injections of views,
because the official documentation specify that injection are made as soon as possible.

they should make an annotation

```
@afterView(R.id.myView)
```